# Using of "Tens hundreds" vs "Thousands"

Tags: american-english, british-english

I've noticed recently that many people from the US used to count hundreds instead of thousands although thousands do exist there. For example the number 2618 would be called: "**twenty six hundreds** and eighteen" instead of "two thousand, six hundreds and eighteen" (see an example [here](https://youtu.be/PKqOgE2tVB0?t=45m29s): at 45:31).

Then my question if it's common in the UK as well as in the US?
I am afraid to use it in the UK and to be sounded weird.

Comment: **Ten Hundred** is often used to mean the time 10:00 AM/PM. It's also used to mean distance (1000).

Comment: I would use "two thousand, six hundred (no s), and eighteen", if I  was saying the number of items.  If I were estimating, I'd say *about* twenty six hundred."  It I am talking about the year, "Twenty-seventeen", if I am talking about money, " I paid twenty-six hundred and eighteen dollars for it." I am in North America, (If it is time, then  we might say sixteen eighteen for 4:18).

Comment: He says twenty six hundred, _without_ the _s_.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a case where there are strict rules, but you could use the following:

- increasing number makes counting in hundreds less likely. Counting in hundreds from 1000 to  2000 is very common. 2000-5000, is less common but not unusual. 5000-9900 is unusual but still acceptable. 10000+ should never be used.
- it's never used for multiples of  1000. E.g. "ten-hundred" is incorrect, but "eleven-hundred" is normal.
- It is normally only used for multiples of 100, but this rule is sometimes broken, especially from 1000-2000.
- there's an implication that when counting in hundreds that you're giving an approximate figure, not an exact one.
- this system is for verbal communication and is rarely, if ever, written.
- this is common in both English and US-English.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the lecturer used twenty-six hundred.

This can happen in AmE when the speaker wants to emphasize the number by making it sound large "twenty-six" sounds larger than "two"

In some cities, this also happens for house addresses where the first two digits can signify the cross street 2618 = the twenty six hundred block (coincidentally, this occurs in NYC where Columbia is located)

Maybe this video will help

> [British Numbers confuse Americans - Numberphile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YBbBbY4qvv4&feature=youtu.be)